# C++ bit fields (passing it in effectively, aka. syntactic sugar)

Tags: c++, flags, bit-fields

I've run into a problem that I feel to be solving inefficiently. I have a bunch of flags (below FLAG_1 and FLAG_2). I want to reset one of them and pass the result into a function. Without a bit field, I could simply write:

```
BYTE flags=FLAG_1 | FLAG_2; // both flags set
func(flags & ~FLAG_2); // preserve Flags in the current scope and pass in "Flags minus FLAG_2"
```

Nice syntax in this situation but cumbersome when working with Flags elsewhere (e.g. in IFs).

Using a bit field the same code becomes more verbose:

```
struct TBitField{
    unsigned flag1:1;
    unsigned flag2:1;
};
TBitField bf={ true, true }; // both flags set
TBitField tmp=bf;
tmp.flag2=false;
func(tmp);
```

Ugly approach in this situation but handy when working with the bit field elsewhere.

Hence, is there a compromise to modify the bit field and pass it over in just one line?

```
TBitField bf={ true, true }; // both flags set
func( bf - FLAG_2 ); // my idealized pseudo-syntax...
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could always use e.g. [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) and overload `operator-` to handle your case.

Comment: what's wrong with `TBitField{bf.flag1, false}`?

Comment: Well, basically nothing if there were just these two flags.
But thanks for the suggestion, this didn't cross my mind.

Answer (score 2):

You are allowed to define methods in your bitfield - it's pretty much a normal `struct`, which is a `class`. You could for example add methods to clear and set bits:

```
struct TBitField {
      unsigned flag1:1;
      unsigned flag2:1;

      TBitField clr2() {
           TBitField tmp = *this;
           tmp.flag2 = false;
           return tmp;
      }
 };
```

Then you use it as for example:

```
 func( bf.clr2() );
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several options I can think of, to implement this "syntactical sugar", as you call it. I'll give a brief outline of one such possible solution. It's not the only one.

Given your definition of a `struct TBitField`, define another class. An enum class will work well

```
 enum class bits {bit_0, bit_1, bit_2 ... }; // And so on.
```

Now, overload the + and - operators. Something like this:

```
TBitField operator+(const TBitField &a, bits bit_number)
{
    // ...
}
```

and

```
TBitField operator-(const TBitField &a, bits bit_number)
{
    // ...
}
```

Now, you can use your desired syntax:

```
func( bf - bits::bit_2 );
```

And this will invoke the corresponding `operator`. The implementation of the two operators should be obvious, and not necessary to spell out, here.

You may even choose to forego a helper class, and simply define:

```
TBitField operator+(const TBitField &a, int bit_number)
{
    // ...
}

TBitField operator-(const TBitField &a, int bit_number)
{
    // ...
}
```

And then simply use:

```
func( bf - 2 );
```

Although that looks slightly confusing, that's why I think that using an explicit helper class is better.

Either approach will likely introduce a little bit of compiler bloat. To remedy this, with most compilers I'd suggest defining both operators as `inline`, and also define overloaded versions that take an rvalue reference as a parameter.

Comment: Hi Sam, thanks for the detailed answer - I've marked it as answering my question. The rvalue reference - I take you mean a move constructor.

Comment: No, as in: "TBitField operator-(TBitField &&a, int bit_number)"